# To use a UIView or UIViewController for timer object?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I've got a UI with several elements, some of which I'd like to encapsulate into their own objects. For example, one object would be a timer (basically just a UILabel sitting in a UIView) with the externally-available members:

- `startTime` (property)
- `start` and `pause` (methods)

(And also a `im_done` NSNotification when the timer reaches 0.) This object and several others would be used together in a single UIViewController.

Would a UIView or UIViewController be more appropriate to subclass for the timer object (and all the others)? Reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902181/subclass-uiview-or-uiviewcontroller) leads me to believe UIView, but for my specific case (especially for the more complicated objects), I'm not sure. Thanks for reading.

EDIT: Just to clarify, I would want all code that implements timer functionality separate from my main view controller. One big reason is so that the timer object would be portable.

Comment: I would recommend subclassing the UIView and not the UIViewController.

Comment: @Sean Thanks for the comment. Just to make sure I understand, is your suggestion to put all the inner workings of my timer (the NSTimer object, etc.) in this UIView subclass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have a subclass of `UIView`, but it should just have the view components to display whatever time information you need. You should also have a `MyTimer` class which encapsulates the timing functionality and provides callbacks on changes (such as the time remaining and perhaps the completion as a separate when the time remaining reaches zero). Ideally the callbacks pass the `MyTimer` and, as a convenience, the remaining time value so you don't need to use the accessor method in the simple use case).

Now, you already have a view controller which is managing your broader view, and it can create add your `UIView` subclass to the main view and create, own and manage the associated `MyTimer` instances which drive those views.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Would that mean that the `MyTimer` class is essentially a view controller?

Comment: no, not a view controller, just a controller (a plain object with allocated responsibility). it has no concept of a view, it just manages time

Comment: OK, so the code in charge of changing the timer's UILabel would remain in my main view controller then?

Comment: You have a choice about wether to put that in the callback provided by `MyTimer`, so it updates the labels in the view subclass directly, or wether the callback passes the value (or just the whole `MyTimer` instance, as a view model) to the view so it can update itself. Both are perfectly valid approaches. So would be updating an intermediary view model class though that is likely overkill....

Answer (score 0):

This I think comes down to preference. You'll include a uiview and uiviewcontroller in a parent view controller differently and this difference can make a uiviewcontroller more difficult if you don't understand containers. I would say best practice would be in a uiviewcontroller but it really is up to you.